# how to match points in dot plot with factors in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, dot

I want a dot plot for mydf below

```
mydf <-  data.frame(city=c(rep(c("Rome","NY","LA"),3)),
                           old=c(11,23,13,24,12,13.5,15,17,22),
                           new=c(12,22,13.5,25,14,15,12,17,14),
                            method=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"))
my_cols <- c("red", "blue", " dark green")
grps <- as.factor(mydf$method)
dotchart(mydf$old, labels = mydf$city,
         groups = grps, gcolor = my_cols,
         color = my_cols[grps],
         cex = 0.6,  pch = 19, xlab = "value")
meth1<- mydf[mydf$method=="a",]
meth2<- mydf[mydf$method=="b",]
meth3<- mydf[mydf$method=="c",]
points(meth1$new, 1:nrow(meth1), col = "orange", pch = 16, cex = 0.6)
points(meth2$new, 1:nrow(meth2), col = "light blue", pch = 16, cex = 0.6)
points(meth2$new, 1:nrow(meth2), col = "green", pch = 16, cex = 0.6)
```

before adding points(), I get plot below, which is what I want as a basis.
[image]

but when I add points, all of them appear in the bottom part of the plot. I want the "new" values corresponding to each method appear in its own part of the plot and a segment line connects the old and the new values accordingly.

[image]
how can I do that in my code? thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The y-axis in the dotchart, under the hood, is really just integers. So you have to provide the correct y-axis values to `points()`:

```
points(meth1$new, 11:13, col = "orange", pch = 16, cex = 0.6)
points(meth2$new, 6:8, col = "light blue", pch = 16, cex = 0.6)
points(meth2$new, 1:3, col = "green", pch = 16, cex = 0.6)
```

I reached those values by just eyeballing the plot and counting up. Note that not all these points will appear if they are outside the range of the original `dotchart` call. You can adjust that by setting `xlim = c(11,25)` or something appropriate in the `dotchart` call.